# Как отправить массив объектов через FormData в приложении на Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, formdata

Есть такой участок кода:

```
    addspare() {
        let app = this;
        app.spares.push({
            type: app.spare.type,
            name: app.spare.name,
            model: app.spare.model,
            parameter: app.spare.parameter,
            qty: app.spare.qty,
            unit: app.spare.unit,
            note: app.spare.note
        });
        console.log(app.spares);
        app.spare = {
            type: '',
            name: '',
            model: '',
            parameter: '',
            qty: 0,
            unit: 'шт',
            note: ''                    
        }
    }
```

Данные из spares правильно отображаются в условной отрисовке v-for.

Но при попытке отправить spares через formdata отправляется [object Object], [objectObject], то есть массив строковых представлений объектов.

formData.append('Spares', app.spares);

Как отправить массив объектов через formdata?
Отправка идет через axios, бэкэнд на laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Просто использовать JSON.stringify при отправке и JSON.parse при получении.

```
formData.append('Spares', JSON.stringify(app.spares));
```

и получение

```
const spares = JSON.parse(req.body.Spares);
```